# font missing in Freelancer game with Wine

Tags: wine, fonts, winetricks, gamepad

Ubuntu16.04
The game Freelancer run well with wine, but one font seem to miss: check on the screenshot, the rectangles might be text.

I have the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package but nothing better, even after restart the system.
[image]

I tried with winetricks>install and select all msfonts, but whatever I do, I go this error message:`sha1sum mismatch! Rename ~/.cache/winetricks/baekmuk/ttf-baekmuk_2.2.orig.tar.gz and try again.`

I still don't know what font is missing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**arial-unicode-ms.ttf** is missing.
Install it in the system or in wine in:
~/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/Fonts/